# Network unreachable with a simple query (wildcard table)

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting a 'query failed' result when executing this simple query from the web UI query composer:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(mydataset, "table_id CONTAINS '2015_09_01'")
```

It takes quite time to answer something and it finally says:

```
Query Failed
Error: Network unreachable.
```

What's happening? Other queries are running well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error is generated by the client-side code when it cannot create a connection to the server or the connection it has breaks. This is generally a sign of network connectivity problems.

You can retry these operations. You can also reset/reboot any hardware between your computer and the internet to see if that helps resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that I have some problem in the way I'm creating the query, since it's not going out from a loop from Google side and it breaks the connection.